# Fibonacci sequence faster, but with different starting numbers (F[n]=F[n-1]+F[n-2])

Tags: c++, c++14, sequence, fibonacci, sequences

(beginner here)

I want to know how to find n-th number of the sequence F[n]=F[n-1]+F[n-2].

Input:

```
F[0] =  a;
F[1] =  b;
a,b < 101
N < 1000000001 
M < 8; M=10^M;
```

a and b are starting sequence numbers.

n is the n-th number of the sequence i need to find.

M is modulo, the number gets very large quickly so F[n]=F[n]%10^M, we find the remainder, because only last digits of the n-th number are needed

The recursive approach is too slow:

```
int fib(int n)
{
   if (n <= 1)
      return n;
   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

The dynamic programming solution which takes O(n) time is also too slow:

```
f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
```

While there are solutions on how to find n-th number faster if first numbers of the sequence are 0 and 1 (n-th number can be found in O(log n)) by using this formula:

```
If n is even then k = n/2:
F(n) = [2*F(k-1) + F(k)]*F(k)

If n is odd then k = (n + 1)/2
F(n) = F(k)*F(k) + F(k-1)*F(k-1)
```

(link to formula and code implementation with it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/)

But this formula does not work if starting numbers are something like 25 and 60. And the recursive approach is too slow.

So I want to know how can I find the n-th number of a sequence faster than O(n). Partial code would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258273/fibonacci-but-with-different-starting-numbers-code-works-in-most-cases-but-no).  It has a link to a formula.

Comment: a) This seems like a math question, not a programming question. b) Your `fib()` is not `O(n)`... it is much, much, much worse than that. Perhaps a first step would be to actually make it `O(n)`?

Comment: The 1000000001st Fibonacci number has 208987640 digits. You will certainly not save that in any standard C++ type, so directly computing the number won't do you any good. You need to find a more clever way.

Comment: Yes the number gets very large, that is why we find the remainder F[n]=F[n]%10^M. I only need last digits of the n-th number

Comment: @ljjlaimis You are missing the point of my comment. Functions evaluating the Fibonacci numbers directly are of no use to you because you cannot save the result anyway.

Comment: Depending on how much you're willing to trade-off potential precision to achieve speed, you can use the mathematical relationship between the Fibonacci sequence and the Golden ratio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This matrix:

```
A = / 1  1 \
    \ 1  0 /
```

When multiplied by the column vector (f<sub>n+1</sub>, f<sub>n</sub>), where f<sub>n</sub> is the nth number in a Fibonacci sequence, will give you the column vector (f<sub>n+2</sub>, f<sub>n+1</sub>), i.e. it will advance you by one step. This works no matter what the initial elements of the sequence were.

For example:

```
/ 1  1 \ / 8 \  =  / 13 \
\ 1  0 / \ 5 /     \ 8  /
```

So the nth fibonacci number is the first element of A<sup>n-1</sup>v, where v is a column vector containing f<sub>1</sub> and f<sub>0</sub>, the first two numbers in your sequence.

Therefore, if you can quickly calculate A<sup>n-1</sup> modulo some number, this will give you f<sub>n</sub>. This can be done using [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which works in O(logn). Just make sure to perform the modulo after every multiplication and addition to prevent the numbers from getting too big.

Comment: Since you can choose the elements of the starting vector, its not restricted to the starting values (1,1), is it? Neat, actually, took me a second to realize its potential benefit!

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this solution